# How to get the mongodb result for the input list of items using $in operator using java in same input order

Tags: java, mongodb

I am in a strange situation, I uses MongoDb 3.2 and java connector.

I have a list of productIds in a particular order which I need to process.

I need to get the products from the mongodb product table

```
 .find({"_id":{$in:[
"PRODUCT50154614","PRODUCT50155694","PRODUCT50131489","PRODUCT50155272","PRODUCT50153244",
"PRODUCT50153301","PRODUCT50155512","PRODUCT50154333","PRODUCT50131166","PRODUCT50155660",
"PRODUCT50155587","PRODUCT50154267","PRODUCT50155611","PRODUCT50154804","PRODUCT50156049",
"PRODUCT50155710","PRODUCT50153194","PRODUCT50131125","PRODUCT50153210","PRODUCT50155702",
"PRODUCT50154176","PRODUCT50155942","PRODUCT50155827","PRODUCT50155629","PRODUCT50154440",
"PRODUCT50154887","PRODUCT50154374","PRODUCT50155314","PRODUCT50154218","PRODUCT50154424",
"PRODUCT50153343","PRODUCT50154770","PRODUCT50154663","PRODUCT50154705","PRODUCT50153251",
"PRODUCT50155959","PRODUCT50155066","PRODUCT50154531","PRODUCT50155470","PRODUCT50155421",
"PRODUCT50155801","PRODUCT50155751","PRODUCT50154523","PRODUCT50153335","PRODUCT50154960",
"PRODUCT50154879","PRODUCT50155082","PRODUCT50132321","PRODUCT50130978","PRODUCT50131414"

]}}).skip(10).limit(20)
```

operation

I expect to get the products in the below order

```
"PRODUCT50155587","PRODUCT50154267","PRODUCT50155611","PRODUCT50154804","PRODUCT50156049",
"PRODUCT50155710","PRODUCT50153194","PRODUCT50131125","PRODUCT50153210","PRODUCT50155702",
"PRODUCT50154176","PRODUCT50155942","PRODUCT50155827","PRODUCT50155629","PRODUCT50154440",
"PRODUCT50154887","PRODUCT50154374","PRODUCT50155314","PRODUCT50154218","PRODUCT50154424"
```

Ie. skipping first 10 products in the $in list and give next 20 products in the same order

I need the exact output for the above query in the sequence of same product Ids which I gave the input with the skip and limit.

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,
Sajith

Comment: you shouldn't use skip() and limit() in this case. Create an array containing all your products _id, and slice it according to your needs before passing it to $in

Comment: Thank you much for your support felix , Why I need this is even If I add any more criteria in search , that also should come with the same orderd as input but lesser product ids which matches.